# Put DropDownList's value to @Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a `Partial View`, with `DropDownList`. And I have `Main View`, with `menu`, where I can call this `Partial View`. I am trying to make `filtering` in `Partial View`, with parameters from it. To do this, I need to put selected `value` of ddl to `@Ajax.ActionLink`. I am trying to do it with `js`, but the page just reloads without calling my `Partial View`.

ActionLink from Main View:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
"Parts",
"PartsPartial",
new
{
    categorie = "add"
},
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "content"
}, new { @class = "button" }
)
```

Form method get in Partial View to make filtering:

```
<form method="get">
    <div>
        <label>Category: </label>
        @Html.DropDownList("categorie", Model.Categories as SelectList,
        htmlAttributes: new { @class="form-control"})

        <label>Brand: </label>
        @Html.DropDownList("brand", Model.Brands as SelectList,
        htmlAttributes: new { @class="form-control" })
        <input type="submit" name="add" value="Filter" />

    </div>
</form>
```

And my controller:

```
public ActionResult PartsPartial(string categorie, int? brand)
    {
        string str = "add";
        List<bs_categories> categoriesList = _db.bs_categories.ToList();
        List<bs_brands> brandsList = _db.bs_brands.ToList();

        if (categorie == str)
        {
            IQueryable<bs_parts> prts = _db.bs_parts;

            PartsViewModel pViewModel = new PartsViewModel
            {
                Parts = prts.ToList(),
                Categories = new SelectList(categoriesList, "categories_id", "categories_name"),
                Brands = new SelectList(brandsList, "brands_id", "brands_name")
            };
            return PartialView(pViewModel);
        }

        decimal categoryId = Convert.ToDecimal(categorie);

        var parts = _db.bs_parts.Where(x => x.parts_category_id == categoryId).OrderBy(x => x.parts_id);

        PartsViewModel pvm = new PartsViewModel
        {
            Parts = parts.ToList(),
            Categories = new SelectList(categoriesList, "categories_id", "categories_name"),
            Brands = new SelectList(brandsList, "brands_id", "brands_name")
        };
        return PartialView(pvm);
    }
```

And here is js to make replace:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#add').click(function () {
            var type = $('#categorie').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                type: 'GET',
                data: { type: type },
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#content').prepend(result);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

May be I missed something?

Comment: Rather using AjaxLink, use simple anchor with url as some data attribute as you have already have code to load view explicitly through ajax!

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the type of input to `button` :

```
<form method="get">
    <div>
        <label>Category: </label>
        @Html.DropDownList("categorie", Model.Categories as SelectList,
        htmlAttributes: new { @class="form-control"})

        <label>Brand: </label>
        @Html.DropDownList("brand", Model.Brands as SelectList,
        htmlAttributes: new { @class="form-control" })
        <input type="button" id="add" name="add" value="Filter" />

    </div>
</form>
```

when you make the type `submit` your ajax code will never called

Comment: I tried, but nothing happened at all. Just pushed the button and that's all. In browser inspect although nothing happens.

Comment: you need to add an id to the input :  <input type="button" id="add" name="add" value="Filter" />